# Installing Windows on Mac from USB drive without having a DVD drive installed

Tags: macos, windows-8.1, boot-camp

I've 15 inch Macbook Pro non-retina. I've removed the DVD drive and install SSD instead, when I try to install Windows on bootcamp drive from USB drive, the USB drive doesn't boot.

I remove the SSD and put back the DVD, it works, and installed the windows.

Now I want to change this Windows 7 to Windows 8, unfortunately I no longer have the DVD drive, what can I do ?

I'm running OSX yosemite

Comment: Mac hardware expects to see an EFI bootloader and GUID partition table on disk type devices.  The standard windows iso to usb tool builds a MBR partition table, and adds an MBR bootlader.

Comment: So, How can i make the ISO image be like EFI

Comment: amd why it works if i put the dvd drive, and didn't work if i un install it ??

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as a person who has done this before, you will need to have a legitimate ISO from Microsoft. You can put the ISO on a USB Drive and point to it from bootcamp. I had this issue using a modified version of Windows for testing devs and it didn't boot.

You will also need to check that the USB drive is formatted correctly. i.e. USB filesystem is NTFS, drop a legitimate ISO on the usb (no need to un-iso the ISO) and try it that way.

There are several sites that provide the vanilla Windows 8/8.1 ISO.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work